Error congela pantalla al usar sheet shadcn ui datatable nextjs
Muy buenas compañeros estoy estancado, se me congela la pantalla al momento de abrir el componente sheet una vez abierto y al darle cerrar o guardar cambios no deja hacer nada se queda congelada la pantalla, toca recargar la pagina para que vuelva a servir los clicks, adjunto el codigo de los componentes
Datatable.tsx
"use client";

import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";
import React from "react";

interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
}

export function DataTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });

  return (
    <div className="rounded-md border">
      <Table>
        <TableHeader>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                return (
                  <TableHead key={header.id}>
                    {header.isPlaceholder
                      ? null
                      : flexRender(
                          header.column.columnDef.header,
                          header.getContext()
                        )}
                  </TableHead>
                );
              })}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
            table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row.id}
                data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
              >
                {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                  <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                    {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))
          ) : (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell colSpan={columns.length} className="h-24 text-center">
                No results.
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}




PageUsers.tsx
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

import { DataTable } from "@/components/dataTable";
import { getDataUsers } from "@/app/api/users/user.api";
import { Metadata, User } from "@/interfaces/user";
import Paginator from "@/components/paginator";
import columns from "./columns";

const UserPage = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [paginationInfo, setPaginationInfo] = useState<Metadata>();

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await getDataUsers(page);
    setUsers(response.rows);
    setPaginationInfo(response.metadata);
  }, [page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
  };

  const handlePrevPage = () => {
    setPage((prevPage) => prevPage - 1);
  };

  const columnsConfig = columns(fetchData);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container mx-auto py-10">
        <DataTable columns={columnsConfig} data={users} />
        {paginationInfo && (
          <Paginator
            metadata={paginationInfo}
            onNext={handleNextPage}
            onPrev={handlePrevPage}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserPage;

ColumnsConfig.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ColumnDef } from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { User } from "@/interfaces/user";
import { deleteUser } from "@/app/api/users/user.api";
import { toast } from "sonner";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuItem,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { MoreHorizontal } from "lucide-react";
import EditUserSheet from "@/components/edituserSheet";

const ActionCell: React.FC<{ user: User; refreshData: () => void }> = ({
  user,
  refreshData,
}) => {
  const [isEditSheetOpen, setIsEditSheetOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDelete = async (id: number) => {
    const response = await deleteUser(id);

    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      toast.success(response.message, {
        className: "bg-green-500 text-white flex items-center p-4 rounded",
      });
      refreshData();
    } else {
      toast.error(response.message, {
        className: "bg-red-500 text-white flex items-center p-4 rounded",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <EditUserSheet
        user={user}
        isOpen={isEditSheetOpen}
        onOpenChange={setIsEditSheetOpen}
        onUserUpdated={refreshData}
      />
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
          <Button variant="ghost" className="h-8 w-8 p-0">
            <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
            <MoreHorizontal className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        </DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
          <DropdownMenuLabel>Acciones</DropdownMenuLabel>
          <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => setIsEditSheetOpen(true)}>
            Editar
          </DropdownMenuItem>
          <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleDelete(Number(user.id))}>
            Eliminar
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        </DropdownMenuContent>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </>
  );
};

const columns = (refreshData: () => void): ColumnDef<User>[] => [
  {
    accessorKey: "name",
    header: "Nombre",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "lastName",
    header: "apellido",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "email",
    header: "email",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "rolesUser",
    header: "Roles",
    cell: ({ row }) => (
      <div>
        {row.original.rolesUser
          .map((roleUser) => roleUser.role.name)
          .join(", ")}
      </div>
    ),
  },
  {
    id: "actions",
    cell: ({ row }) => (
      <ActionCell user={row.original} refreshData={refreshData} />
    ),
  },
];

export default columns;

UserSheet.tsx
    "use client"
     import { editUserSchema } from "@/lib/zod";
      import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import React from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { z } from "zod"
import {
  Sheet,
  SheetClose,
  SheetContent,
  SheetDescription,
  SheetFooter,
  SheetHeader,
  SheetTitle,
} from "./ui/sheet";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import {
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormControl,
  FormMessage,
  Form,
} from "./ui/form";
import { Input } from "./ui/input";
import { User } from "@/interfaces/user";

interface EditUserSheetProps {
  user: User;
  isOpen: boolean;
  onOpenChange: (open: boolean) => void;
  onUserUpdated: () => void;
}

const EditUserSheet = ({
  user,
  isOpen,
  onOpenChange,
  onUserUpdated,
}: EditUserSheetProps) => {
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof editUserSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(editUserSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: user.name,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
      roles: user.rolesUser.map((roleUser) => Number(roleUser.role.id)),
      password: user.password,
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof editUserSchema>) => {
    console.log(values);
    onUserUpdated();
    onOpenChange(false);
    console.log(isOpen);
    form.reset();
  };

  return (
    <Sheet open={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange}>
      <SheetContent>
        <SheetHeader>
          <SheetTitle>Editar Usuario</SheetTitle>
          <SheetDescription>
            Realiza cambios en la información del usuario aquí. Haz clic en
            guardar cuando hayas terminado.
          </SheetDescription>
        </SheetHeader>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form
            onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            className="space-y-4 py-4"
          >
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="name"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Nombre</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input type="text" {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="lastName"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Apellido</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input type="text" {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="email"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input type="email" {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="password"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Contraseña</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input type="password" {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <SheetFooter>
              <SheetClose asChild>
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  variant="outline"
                  onClick={() => onOpenChange(false)}
                >
                  Cancelar
                </Button>
              </SheetClose>
              <Button type="submit">Guardar cambios</Button>
            </SheetFooter>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </SheetContent>
    </Sheet>
  );
};

export default EditUserSheet

No se me ocurre nada solo ocurre cuando se muestra el componente sheet, lo cambie por un dialog de shadcn y pasa lo mismo se abre el componente lo cierro y se congela la pantalla no deja clickear en nungun lado

Esta soluciando, si a alguien mas le pasa solo añadir esta liena de codigo en el dropdow menu   modal={false}
